# How do i add one objects propertys value to another object as new propertys value

Tags: javascript

For example  i have an object with key 1:

```
1:{{name:alice,surname:doe}}
```

i have another object with same key 1:

```
1:"A"
```

By iterating we check if both keys are matching ( in this case 1 and 1 ) so we add second objects A to first object as grade:A so final object looks like

```
1:{{name:alice,surname:doe,grade:A}}
```

I am adding a picture to explain better.

[image]

this is what i have tried: the problem is 00001 key is missing:

```
    Object.keys(localallcourseobject).forEach(function(key){
  if(key in passedcoursesgrade) {
    var c = Object.assign(localallcourseobject[key],{grade:passedcoursesgrade[key]});

   console.log(c);

  }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Titm4.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I prepared this snippet for you which will look for same attributes in `a` and `b` and will add matches as `grade` attribute in object `c`:

```js
var a = {1: {name:'alice',surname:'doe'}}
var b = {1:"A"}
var c = Object.assign({}, a)

for (var attr in a) {
  for (var attr_ in b) {
    if (attr == attr_) {
      c.grade = b[attr_]
    }
  }
}

console.log(c)
```

if you just want to replace the `1` attribute with the object do the following:

```js
var a = {1: {name:'alice',surname:'doe'}}
var b = {1:"A"}
var c = Object.assign(a[1], {grade: b[1]})

console.log(c)
```

greetings

Comment: hi thanks for the answer but can you edit it like adding grade in 1:{} like name and surname ?(i mean same place)

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), it allows you to be able to combine various object values. Below is a simple way to combine both objects into one with the structure you want.

```js
var a = {1: {name:'alice',surname:'doe'}}
var b = {1:"A"}
var c = Object.assign(a[1], {grade: b[1]})

console.log(c)
```

Comment: hi i tried this can you check my edit there is 1 problem